# docker-compose insert an extra command upon container creation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project where each service has its own command to run upon startup.
I want to add an extra command before the one given in the `docker-compose.yml` that will execute only when the container is first created.

Since I'm not sure this is possible, it is also acceptable for me to manually run commands before calling `docker-compose up`.

Given the following `docker-compose.yml`
version: '2.3'

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  serv1:
    image: my_image
    command: some startup command

  serv2:
    image: my_image
    command: some startup command 2
```

I have tried to run the following

```
$ docker-compose run serv1 my_creation_command
$ docker-compose run serv2 my_creation_command
$ docker-compose up
```

But this results in the first two commands creating containers `projectname_serv1_run_1` and `projectname_serv2_run_1` and the third command creating `projectname_serv1_1` and `projectname_serv2_1`

This is obviously a problem since the `my_creation_command` never ran on the containers created by the `up` command

Any solution that will manage to get a custom command executed only on the creation part will be acceptable

Answer (score 2):

A possible and easy solution is to wrap init command and run command into a unique script (let's call it `init_or_run`) :

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  serv1:
    image: my_image
    command: init_and_run

  serv2:
    image: my_image
    command: init_and_run_2
```

These scripts have to handle init and run cases. I've already done that for databases (see example below).

#### Example (with a database)

- in `init_and_run`'s init case, creates database/tables
- in `init_and_run`'s run case, just starts the database daemon

Checking if you have to run init part of the script here could be just verifying if database exist :

```sh
if database_does_not_exist
then
    create_database_and_tables # init case
fi

run_database_daemon # in both cases, run database daemon
```

With this solution, you just have to run `docker-compose up` to start your services, without caring if service have already been initialized, because `init_and_run` script will handle both cases (init and run or just run).

Comment: That's a good direction, but I don't have a way to check if `my_creation_command` was already executed or not on a container

Comment: Could you just create a dummy file just after executing `my_creation_command`, and check if this file exists to know if `my_creation_command` have already been executed?

Comment: I can, but this is kind of a dirty solution, there must be something cleaner

Comment: I surely agree that, and I'll be happy to know a cleaner solution :) But it seems that creating a script doing both init and run phases is the only way to do what you want (check the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407477/how-to-run-a-command-once-in-docker-compose). But to use that, you have to know if `my_creation_command` have been executed. Don't you have any way to check if init command has been run? What does exactly this command?

Comment: the command runs a `pip install --upgrade -r requirements` and I don't want it to run every time, just when it is being created. I can check if the libraries are installed - but if they do I still wish to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: So then, if I understand, you always want to run `pip install --upgrade -r requirements` to install **or** upgrade dependencies, am I wrong? If dependencies are already installed, running this command only upgrades them, right?

Comment: Yep, but its not relevant to go into that. My question is not general given that you can't check if it was already ran or not - answer should be agnostic to the init command

Comment: In all cases I've encountered, you can always know if init command have been executed. Otherwise, if there is no way to tell if the init command have run, then you probably don't want to separate init/run cases. In your particular example, it seems like you do not need init command since you always want to run it (to install or upgrade dependencies).