# What is the correct way to seed a rails app in docker so it can be started repeatedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a rails app with mysql as the DB, that I'm trying to dockerize, so I can eventually deploy it with `docker-machine`. When I run `docker-compose up` the first time, it initializes correctly and seeds the database, like it's supposed to. However, after I shut it down, the second time I run `docker-compose up`, it fails with the following error, because the seed content is already present:

```
web_1     | ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'antun@example.com' for key 'index_users_on_email'
```

In my docker-compose.yml file, I'm doing the following under the web service:

```
command: /bin/sh -c "bin/wait-for db:3306 -- rm -f /home/ubuntu/MY_APP/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:seed && rails server puma -p 80"
```

I'm using the ! method approach in db/seeds.rb, since I understand that's considered a best-practice:

```
u = User.new(
  {email: "antun@example.com", encrypted_password: "XXXXX", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, first_name: "Antun", last_name: "LAST_NAME", provider: "facebook", uid: "12345", username: "antun"}
) 
u.save!(validate: false)
```

I know I could skip the ! in `u.save!()` but as I said, I understand it's a best practice to use it in the seeds file, so that it fails. **My question is: what is the correct, best-practice approach for creating and seeding a DB only on first run with docker-compose?** Once it's live, I want to make sure that subsequent updates to the app (which may include migrations/additional seeds for new data types) work smoothly, without erasing data that's in the database.

Here's the full docker-compose.yml file:

```
docker-compose.yml

    version: '3.1'
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXX
          MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXXX
          MYSQL_USER: XXXXX
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXXX
      web:
        build: .
        command: /bin/sh -c "bin/wait-for db:3306 -- rm -f /home/ubuntu/MY_APP/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:seed && rails server puma -p 80"
        volumes: 
          - $PWD:/MY_APP
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        links:
          - "db:database" 
        env_file:
          - .env.production
        depends_on:
          - db
      worker:
        build: .
        command: /bin/sh -c "bundle exec bin/delayed_job -n 1 --log-dir=/home/ubuntu/MY_APP/shared/log/delayed_job.log --pool='notifications-poller:1' --pool='broadcast,default,elasticsearch,firebase:2' restart && bundle exec shoryuken --logfile '/home/ubuntu/MY_APP/shared/log/shoryuken.log' --config '/home/ubuntu/MY_APP/config/shoryuken_staging.yml' -R"
        links:
          - "db:database"
        volumes:
          - $PWD:/MY_APP
          - '/home/ubuntu/MY_APP/node_modules'
        env_file:
          - .env.production
        depends_on:
          - db
```

Comment: I definitely want to maintain the data. I'm new to Docker so I'm looking for the correct way to seed/create a database with Rails. I was following a guide that had `bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate` in the docker-compose.yml file. I simply added the `db:seed` to that place. Are you implying that I should move all of those out of the docker-compose.yml file, and into the dockerfile perhaps? Or is there a way to put something in docker-compose.yml so it only gets run the first time?

Comment: I feel your pain, Docker is very hard to get into IMO, and sometimes doesn't seem worth it to me. Anyways, this might help you https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

Comment: In that document, it seems that the approach they're proposing is not to automate creation of the DB, but to have the *user* manually create it by running `docker-compose run web rake db:create`. Is that really how it's done? It seems very un-Docker-like to me, as it requires a user to know which commands to run in order to setup and deploy.

Comment: I'm not a docker expert by any means but that is how I do it. There are other options discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407477/how-to-run-a-command-once-in-docker-compose

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`ActiveRecord::Relation#find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) instead:

```
User.find_or_create_by(email: "antun@example.com", encrypted_password: "XXXXX", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, first_name: "Antun", last_name: "LAST_NAME", provider: "facebook", uid: "12345", username: "antun")
```

---

Answering to your comment; I'm afraid the repository is already unmaintained, but you can use the [branch](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump/pull/148) I just made for this.

If you see the changes, you're able to do:

```
SeedDump.dump(ModelName, method: :find_or_create_by)
# "ModelName.find_or_create_by([\n  {name: \"<name>\", status: nil},\n...)\n"
```

---

Answering to your last comment and your question:

> What is the correct way to seed a rails app in docker so it can be started repeatedly

I don't know if it's the *correct*, but an easy one; as you're using MySQL just use the tools it provides. You can dump and import the data from any environment, that'll keep the integrity of your data, which might be faster and less error-prone.

Comment: This would probably work, but I am using the seed_dump gem (https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) to generate the seed files, which auto-generates them based on some initial setup that I do manually while developing. I could modify them of course, but then it kind of defeats the benefit of using the seed dump.

Comment: I really appreciate the input here, and I think your approach will solve the error at seed time. However the picture I am building from Eyeslandic's comments in the question, and from some more digging is: I should **not** be running `rake db:create db:migrate db:seed` directly in a command docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Well, that's true @antun. What you usually do is just to migrate your database with the Rails task after the changes you may produce. And for handling the data from your production database you can dump and import the data to your development environment just by the command line many DBMS provide. I don't see the point on using this library, when having dbs storing many information it's slower than the options your DBMS might provide.